# How to create an Image from a url Codenameone

Tags: java, image, codenameone

I need to make a new Image instance from a string that has the url of the image.
E.g. http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png

This type of urls come from a JSONParser and I want to use them to populate the icons of a multibutton list.

I use the following **getItemAt** method of this Model class put data on a multibutton list. Each multibutton has an icon and some lines. I have named Line1 as *name* and Line2 as *rating*. I want from the string url to make an Image so I can change the multibutton icon in place of defaultIcon in h.put("icon", defaultIcon) line.

```
static class Model implements ListModel {
    public Object getItemAt(int index) {
        Hashtable h      = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable entry  = (Hashtable) results.elementAt(index);
        String    name   = (String) entry.get("name");
        Double    rating = (Double) entry.get("rating");
        String    url    = (String) entry.get("icon");

        h.put("name", name);
        h.put("icon", defaultIcon); // change defaultIcon with an Image from url String

        if (rating == null) {
            h.put("rating", "Not rated");
        } else {
            h.put("rating", "Rating: " + rating.toString());
        }

        return h;
    }
```

Comment: What type of image? BufferedImage? And also please tell us what you have you tried and how isn't it working. Not my down-vote by the way. Also my future up-vote if you supply my requested information. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage` which will asynchronously download the image, place it in the Hashtable for the list in the proper location. Refresh the list and cache the image in storage in case you ask for it again.

It can also scale your image to a fixed dimension as part of the service.

Comment: That seems to be advanced to me. I am trying to extend the `MapsDemo` and display the places returned from `showResturantsOnMap` as a list with icon, name, rating and distance. To create this list I used the logic from `Contacts.java` in the `KitchenSink` demo. Sorry but I don't understand how to use your information.

Comment: The images need to be downloaded in the background so the list will be filled as you use it. Just place a placeholder instance in the "photo" entry in your hashtable and for every entry in the list (when you create the entry instance) call ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(theURL, listInstance, offsetInTheList, "photo", uniqueIdForThisEntryCanBeAnyString, new Dimension(widthOfPreviewImage, heightOfPreviewImage);

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to obtain an image from an url

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
```

this could also work

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. There is conflict with codenameone api Image class. Here is the api: https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html
I think my solution is in ImageDownloadService class but I don't understand how to use it in my case.

Comment: That's a Codename One question, not an AWT question so this answer is incorrect.