# Using ImageDownloadService for MultiButton Icons

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

Is it possible to use the ImageDownloadService (especially the createImageToStorage method) for icons in a MultiButton ComponentGroup?

If yes, could you post a working example?

Comment: This Question is the specialised Version of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979247/how-to-create-an-image-from-a-url-codenameone), which is still not answered.

Comment: That question was answered by myself, the person asking failed to accept the answer or ask followup questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getIconComponent()` and pass that to the `ImageDownloadService` instead of the multi button itself.

Comment: ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(url, multiButton.getIconComponent(), uniqueId, null);